# How to change position Textview get using context

Tags: android, textview

```
TableRow tr1 = new TableRow(context);
TextView hbar = new TextView(context);

tr1.addView(hbar, 0);

tl.addView(tr1,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

I need to change the possition of textview.

`hbar.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);` not worked. and also tried with set `layoutparams`. any suggestions ??

Answer (score 0):

set the `layoutperams` to the `TableRow` with `LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT`, and then try it once.

```
TableRow tr1 = new TableRow(context);
TextView hbar = new TextView(context);

tr1.addView(hbar, 0);

tl.addView(tr1,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

tl.setPadding(10,0,0,0);
```

here views are creating dynamically, we unable to change the positions in `onCreate` method,  try to override the `onWindowFocusChange()` and then do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    //your textview.
    tl.setPadding(10,0,0,0);
}
```